# Why is the FTC $f(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^x f(t) dt$ and not $f(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^x f(x) dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, derivatives

I understand how I can go from one to another, but that's only because of the relationship between derivative and integral in terms of computation and basic algebraic manipulation

But I don't really understood where the $t$'s come from. Right now, I don't see much difference between $f(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^x t^2 \, dt$ and $f(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^x x^2 \, dx$

added: The reason for the question is that axes are $x$ and $y$, and the function is $f(x)=y$, so where does the $t$ come from? (From the looks of the preliminary answers, I seem to understand it as $f(t)=y$ because two x's would be ambiguous)

Comment: Because you can't use the same letter for two different purposes.

Comment: They mean exactly the same thing.

Comment: @saulspatz no they don't.  $\int_a^x f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ is meaningless.

Comment: @user10354138 No it isn't.  The $x$ under the integral sign is a dummy variable that has absolutely nothing to to with the $x$ in upper limit of integration.

Comment: @saulspatz Maybe these $x$s are different variables. But it's bad style, and poterntially confusing, to use the same letter for both.

Comment: As Mr. @saulspatz mentions there isn't any difference between the two. Different letters are used just to avoid confusion. For example: What is $f(sin x)$?

Comment: @AnginaSeng I agree with that.

Answer (score 5):

The symbol $\int_a^x x^2 \, dx$ is very misleading and extremely sloppy. It should be avoided at all costs (unless you know what you're doing... in which case I'd still say it's sloppy).
\begin{align}
\int_a^xt^2 \, dt = \int_a^x u^2 \, du = \int_a^x \xi^2 \, d \xi = \int_a^x (\ddot{\smile})^2 \, d \ddot{\smile} = \int_a^x \sharp^2 \, d \sharp
\end{align}
are all different ways of writing down a definite integral. You're integrating the squaring function $F: \xi \mapsto \xi^2$ from the limits $a$ to $x$. Note that the variable inside makes no difference at all; it doesn't matter whether you're calling it $\xi,\eta,\alpha,\beta,\ddot{\smile},t,s,\sharp$, whatever, it doesn't matter in any way. It is what we call a "dummy variable".

**The only thing you should NOT do is reuse the same letter $x$ for two different purposes**. Here, the letter $x$ is being used as the upper limit of integration, so of course we shouldn't reuse it.

Comment: The $\ddot\smile$ was really cool. +1